# Apple Push Notification Gateway Connection, Notification not received

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I am sending notifications many a time from my iOS application. For this i have used APNS-PHP library for sending it from server to Apple Push Notification Gateway.

Here is the code.

```
public function publishAPush($requestBody){

    try {

        $toUserId=$requestBody->{KEY_USERID};
        $toUserType=$requestBody->{KEY_USERTYPE};


        $soundFileName=$requestBody->{"sound"};
        $badge=$requestBody->{"badge"};
        $customMessage=$requestBody->{"custom"};
        $alertMesssage=$requestBody->{"alert"};
        if(!empty ($toUserId)){  
                $push = new ApnsPHP_Push(
                                    ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX,
                                    'file.pem');

                // Set the Root Certificate Autority to verify the Apple remote peer
                $push->setRootCertificationAuthority('entrust_root_certification_authority.pem');
                // Connect to the Apple Push Notification Service
                $push->connect();
                // Instantiate a new Message with a single recipient
                $message = new ApnsPHP_Message($deviceToken);
                // Set badge icon to "3"
                $message->setBadge($badgeCount);
                // Set a simple welcome text
                $message->setText($alertMesssage);
                // Play the default sound
                $message->setSound($soundFileName);
                $message->setCustomProperty("custom", json_encode($customMessage));
                $push->add($message);

                // Send all messages in the message queue
                $push->send();

                // Disconnect from the Apple Push Notification Service
                $push->disconnect();

                // Examine the error message container
                $aErrorQueue = $push->getErrors();

                if (!empty($aErrorQueue)) {
                    Logger::getRootLogger()->error("Apple Server Error= " . $aErrorQueue);
                }else{
                    Logger::getRootLogger()->info("Message Send successfully to " . $toUserId);
                }
            }
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        Logger::getRootLogger()->error("Publish a Push= " . $exc);  
    }
}
```

But it happens that many a times I don't receive them, so what could be a possible solution for it. Is it because I am connecting and disconnecting it.

What would be a better way to write this code?

Answer (score 0):

do you receive the token in the ios app correctly?

also, use this ( https://github.com/jPaolantonio/SimplePush/blob/master/simplepush.php ) short example and then modify it yourself.
this example is working for me.

Comment: Yes, tokens are received correctly when a notification is received.